# Should I log transform the data if the dataset is small?

Tags: dataset, normalization

Suppose I have a dataset with only about 25 rows.

All the relevant columns are all integers. The ranges of them go from 1 million to 100 million, and the distributions are all skewed right.

In this instance, should I bother normalizing the data (log transform) to create a normal distribution?

Comment: 1) Why does logging the data guarantee a normal distribution? 2) Why do you want a normal distribution? 3) Why does the small sample size matter?